# BeaconManager updateScanPeriods does not change the scan rate

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am using the altbeacon library for the BLE scan, on Android O+, BLE is in foreground mode, all other pre-Android O devices run on background. Scan started no problem, and another background job will change the scan period in certain situation, the code executed and i see the setting applied, but i dont see the scan rate get reduced.

Here is the code i use to refresh the scan rate (after BLE is activated and scanning):

```
public static int SHORT_SCAN_PERIOD = 2 * 1000;
public static int SHORT_BETTWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD = 4 * 1000;
public static int LONG_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD = 3600 * 1000;

private void refreshBLEScanPeriod() {
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getApplicationContext());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.d(logTag, "Refreshing BLE scan period");
        //beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(Config.SHORT_SCAN_PERIOD);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(Config.SHORT_BETTWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);
    } else {
        //beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(Config.SHORT_SCAN_PERIOD);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(Config.SHORT_BETTWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);
    }

    try {
        beaconManager.applySettings();
        beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        Log.d(logTag, "BLE scan period updated to SHORT");

        AppDefaultNotification appDefaultNotification = new AppDefaultNotification(getApplicationContext());
        appDefaultNotification.buildNotification();

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(logTag, "Unable to reset scan period " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is the code how i started the BLE:

```
    beaconScanner = BeaconScanner.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        appDefaultNotification = new AppDefaultNotification(this);
        Log.d(logTag, "starting BLE foreground service");
        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(Config.SHORT_SCAN_PERIOD);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(Config.SHORT_BETTWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);

        /**
         * For the above foreground scanning service to be useful, you need to disable
         * JobScheduler-based scans (used on Android 8+) and set a fast background scan
         * cycle that would otherwise be disallowed by the operating system.
         */
        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);

        beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(appDefaultNotification.buildNotification(), Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE);


    } else {
        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);

        /**
         * Every 60s scan for 20s
         */
        // set the duration of the scan to be 1.1 seconds
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(Config.SHORT_SCAN_PERIOD);
        // set the time between each scan to be 30 seconds
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(Config.SHORT_BETTWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);


        setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(sharedPreferences.getInt(Config.KEY_BLE_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD, Config.SHORT_BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD));
    }
    /**
     * simply constructing this class and holding a reference to it in your custom Application
     * class will automatically cause the BeaconLibrary to save battery whenever the application
     * is not visible.  This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
     */
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));      // iBeacon Layout
```

here is the log:

> 09-21 22:00:36.594 5776-5949: BeaconManager Before udpating scan
>   period, beaconMgr between scan period 4000
>
> 09-21 22:00:36.594 5776-5949: BeaconManager Refreshing BLE scan period
>   to LONG
>
> 09-21 22:00:36.595 5776-5949: BeaconManager BLE scan period updated
>
> 09-21 22:00:36.689 5776-5949: BeaconManager Current beaconMgr between
>   scan period 3600000
>
> And here is the long showing BLE is still actively scanning:
>
> 09-21 22:03:59.821 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='45.70308117629712}
>
> 09-21 22:03:59.827 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='45.70308117629712}
>
> 09-21 22:04:00.960 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='47.328112013435565}
>
> 09-21 22:04:00.965 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='47.328112013435565}
>
> 09-21 22:04:02.082 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='47.88079569698942}
>
> 09-21 22:04:02.086 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='47.88079569698942}
>
> 09-21 22:04:03.225 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='49.0029516131644}
>
> 09-21 22:04:03.232 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='49.0029516131644}
>
> 09-21 22:04:05.462 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='49.57251774840043}
>
> 09-21 22:04:05.467 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='49.57251774840043}
>
> 09-21 22:04:59.948 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='49.0029516131644}
>
> 09-21 22:04:59.956 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='49.0029516131644}
>
> 09-21 22:05:01.073 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='56.22605173071153}
>
> 09-21 22:05:01.083 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='56.22605173071153}
>
> 09-21 22:05:15.786 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='49.0029516131644}
>
> 09-21 22:05:15.794 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='49.0029516131644}
>
> 09-21 22:05:18.031 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='50.7288634831964}
>
> 09-21 22:05:18.036 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='50.7288634831964}
>
> 09-21 22:05:20.267 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='56.22605173071153}
>
> 09-21 22:05:20.272 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='56.22605173071153}
>
> 09-21 22:05:21.400 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='50.7288634831964}
>
> 09-21 22:05:21.404 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='50.7288634831964}
>
> 09-21 22:05:22.528 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='45.70308117629712}
>
> 09-21 22:05:22.533 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='45.70308117629712}
>
> 09-21 22:05:23.657 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='44.126620660525674}
>
> 09-21 22:05:23.661 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='44.126620660525674}
>
> 09-21 22:05:24.772 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='43.465561542707945}
>
> 09-21 22:05:24.773 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='43.465561542707945}
>
> 09-21 22:05:28.180 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='44.51624911719877}
>
> 09-21 22:05:28.189 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='44.51624911719877}
>
> 09-21 22:05:34.975 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='43.985672374000856}
>
> 09-21 22:05:34.977 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='43.985672374000856}
>
> 09-21 22:05:36.107 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='43.20355217003139}
>
> 09-21 22:05:36.112 5776-5776: Detected beacon
>   BeaconSignal{uuid='50765cb7-d9ea-4e21-99a4-fa879613a492',
>   major='52259', minor='29402', distance='43.20355217003139}

Comment: Is the problem only on Android 8+ with the foreground scanning service that the new intervals do not get apploed?

Comment: right now i only change the scan rate on Android 8+ device, and from the log above, seems like the setting is loaded, just not taking effect. 09-21 22:00:36.594 5776-5949: BeaconManager Before udpating scan period, beaconMgr between scan period 4000

09-21 22:00:36.594 5776-5949: BeaconManager Refreshing BLE scan period to LONG

09-21 22:00:36.595 5776-5949: BeaconManager BLE scan period updated

09-21 22:00:36.689 5776-5949: BeaconManager Current beaconMgr between scan period 3600000

Comment: Hi David, I test again today after i reboot the device and that seems to behave better, at least i see that the scanning rate is different, i will monitor it couple more days. Meanwhile, i have a more general question to ask, i notice that sometime i needed to restart Bluetooth in order to get the scanning working, is that an expected behavior? Or is there any status type of function that i can call and programmatically restart Bluetooth?

Comment: @davidgyoung more update,  seems like after i added both setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod and setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod, the device start reducing the scan rate, if i just do setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod, the app will only reduce the scan rate while app is in foreground, when the app go to background, even BLE is started as foreground mode, it still go back to use the fast scanning rate. Any thought? Also a side question, from time to time, i need to restart bluetooth in order to get the scanning start working (it happened on transmission too, but less often), any idea?

Comment: See here on resolving Bluetooth freezes:. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450865/1461050

Comment: it is important to know if your app is in foreground or background mode so you can control the proper scan period.  if you really want it to be the same for both foreground and background, set both scan periods to be the same as you tried.

Comment: @davidgyoung, i use foreground mode on Android 8+, as i mentioned, not sure why i need to set both foreground and background scan period in order for my Pixel 2 to works. By the way, thanks for the BluetoothMedic

Comment: I added the BluetoothMedic, but there is no disable function, how should i turn it off?

Comment: if you enable power cycling with the medic, the API currently has no way to turn it off.  If you enable periodic tests, you can call again with NO_TEST to disable them.  I cannot explain why you need to set both foreground and background mode unless you use BackgroundPowerSaver or change the background mode manually.

Comment: @davidgyoung i do enable backgrounPowerSaver regardless foreground or background, should I just limited it to background only?

Comment: BackgroundPowerSaver is what changes your app between foreground and background mode automatically based on whether an activity is in the foreground. If you want this behavior, understand that the foreground vs. background scan periods may be active based on this automatic change.  If you want to manage these scan rates yourself (which it sounds like you do) I suggest you simply do not use BackgroundPowerSaver at all, and simply leave it in foreground mode all the time.  This way, you only need to configure the foreground scan periods.