# BluetoothMedic not able to recover BLE transmission and scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

My BLE service is running in foreground and i tried to enable the Medic as suggested in previous post ([Android Beacon Library - correct use of BluetoothMedic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448920/android-beacon-library-correct-use-of-bluetoothmedic/51450865#51450865)), in one of my Samsung device, a notification pop up reporting transmitter is not working, i think it tried to restart it but it did not recover. Here is my code:

```
    bluetoothMedic.enablePowerCycleOnFailures(context);
    bluetoothMedic.enablePeriodicTests(context, BluetoothMedic.SCAN_TEST | BluetoothMedic.TRANSMIT_TEST);
    bluetoothMedic.setNotificationsEnabled(true, R.drawable.ic_stat_jugo);
```

Here is the logs:

```
09-26 22:01:57.549 1348-1348/? D/MultiSimUtils: isSimStateReadyorNotReady() : simSlot = 0, simState = NOT_READY\
09-26 22:01:57.549 1348-1348/? D/CarrierText: setText : \
09-26 22:01:58.535 677-677/? D/WifiTrafficPoller: notifyOnDataActivity() - mBusMaxLock.acquire()\
09-26 22:01:58.536 1348-1348/? D/NetworkController: updateCarrierText : SiuFuiHse - Downstair\
09-26 22:01:58.537 1348-1348/? D/NetworkController: dynamicallyReduceTextSize : mDisplayMetrics.densityDpi160\
09-26 22:01:58.537 1291-1291/? E/wpa_supplicant: IAPP SNAP_HDR Mismatch\
09-26 22:01:58.544 1348-1348/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast com.samsung.systemui.ACTION_VOIP_CALL_STATE_CHANGED, #start\
09-26 22:01:58.544 1348-1348/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast com.samsung.systemui.ACTION_VOIP_CALL_STATE_CHANGED, #end\
09-26 22:01:58.544 1348-1348/? D/CarrierText: updateCarrierText(): 0,DefaultText = No network connection\
09-26 22:01:58.544 1348-1348/? D/MultiSimUtils: isSimStateReadyorNotReady() : simSlot = 0, simState = NOT_READY\
09-26 22:01:58.544 1348-1348/? D/CarrierText: setText : \
09-26 22:01:59.157 677-1134/? D/InputReader: Input event(4): value=1 when=504506898133000\
09-26 22:01:59.158 677-1134/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.519 ] when=504506898133000\
09-26 22:01:59.158 677-1133/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (1348): action: 0x0, toolType: 1\
09-26 22:01:59.158 1348-1348/? D/ViewRootImpl@36c0742[StatusBar]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0\
09-26 22:01:59.212 677-1134/? D/InputReader: Input event(4): value=0 when=504506952441000\
09-26 22:01:59.212 677-1134/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=504506952441000\
09-26 22:01:59.212 677-1133/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (1348): action: 0x1, toolType: 1\
09-26 22:01:59.213 1348-1348/? D/ViewRootImpl@36c0742[StatusBar]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1\
09-26 22:01:59.536 677-677/? D/WifiTrafficPoller: notifyOnDataActivity() - mBusMaxLock.acquire()\
09-26 22:01:59.537 1348-1348/? D/NetworkController: updateCarrierText : SiuFuiHse - Downstair\
09-26 22:01:59.538 1348-1348/? D/NetworkController: dynamicallyReduceTextSize : mDisplayMetrics.densityDpi160\
09-26 22:01:59.545 1348-1348/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast com.samsung.systemui.ACTION_VOIP_CALL_STATE_CHANGED, #start\
09-26 22:01:59.545 1348-1348/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast com.samsung.systemui.ACTION_VOIP_CALL_STATE_CHANGED, #end\
09-26 22:01:59.545 1348-1348/? D/CarrierText: updateCarrierText(): 0,DefaultText = No network connection\
09-26 22:01:59.545 1348-1348/? D/MultiSimUtils: isSimStateReadyorNotReady() : simSlot = 0, simState = NOT_READY\
09-26 22:01:59.545 1348-1348/? D/CarrierText: setText : \
09-26 22:01:59.561 1291-1291/? E/wpa_supplicant: IAPP SNAP_HDR Mismatch\
...
...
...
09-26 22:02:00.302 11594-11594/? D/oneconnect[1.0.00.78][100000078]: HidProfile.onServiceDisconnected - 4\
09-26 22:02:00.306 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@44c59d4\
09-26 22:02:00.307 1335-1335/? D/HealthService: Received stop request...Stopping profile...\
09-26 22:02:00.307 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@44c59d4\
09-26 22:02:00.307 1335-1335/? E/BluetoothAdapterService: onProfileServiceStateChanged() serviceName=com.android.bluetooth.hdp.HealthService, state=10, Message sending\
09-26 22:02:00.307 1335-1335/? D/HealthService: notifyProfileServiceStateChanged\
09-26 22:02:00.308 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@44c59d4\
09-26 22:02:00.309 1335-1335/? D/PanService: Received stop request...Stopping profile...\
09-26 22:02:00.311 1335-1335/? D/EnhancedTetheringManager: stop\
09-26 22:02:00.312 1335-1335/? D/EnhancedTetheringManager: tetherEnabled : false\
09-26 22:02:00.312 1335-1335/? D/ETMLeHelper: stopAdvertise\
09-26 22:02:00.313 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_OFF\
09-26 22:02:00.313 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_OFF\
09-26 22:02:00.313 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: stop advertising\
09-26 22:02:00.313 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: wrapper is null\
09-26 22:02:00.313 1335-1335/? D/EnhancedTetheringManager: removeNapWakeAlarm\
09-26 22:02:00.321 677-1929/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm calling from uid:1002 pid :1335 / op:PendingIntent\{df6eb4f: PendingIntentRecord\{bee72dc com.android.bluetooth broadcastIntent\}\}\
09-26 22:02:00.322 1335-1335/? D/EnhancedTetheringManager: cancelFindTetherServer\
09-26 22:02:00.322 1335-1335/? D/ETMLeHelper: stopScan\
09-26 22:02:00.322 1335-1335/? D/EnhancedTetheringManager: removePanuWakeAlarm\
09-26 22:02:00.324 677-3889/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm calling from uid:1002 pid :1335 / op:PendingIntent\{860ed6b: PendingIntentRecord\{55de0c8 com.android.bluetooth broadcastIntent\}\}\
09-26 22:02:00.325 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@44c59d4\
09-26 22:02:00.326 1335-1335/? E/BluetoothAdapterService: onProfileServiceStateChanged() serviceName=com.android.bluetooth.pan.PanService, state=10, Message sending\
09-26 22:02:00.326 1335-1335/? D/PanService: notifyProfileServiceStateChanged\
09-26 22:02:00.330 677-677/? D/BluetoothPan: BluetoothPAN Proxy object disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.331 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@44c59d4\
09-26 22:02:00.331 1348-1348/? D/BluetoothPan: BluetoothPAN Proxy object disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.331 1348-1348/? D/PanProfile: Bluetooth service disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.331 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothPan: BluetoothPAN Proxy object disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.331 10977-10977/? D/PanProfile: Bluetooth service disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.332 1335-1335/? D/SapService: Received stop request...Stopping profile...\
09-26 22:02:00.332 1335-1335/? V/SapService: stop()\
09-26 22:02:00.332 1335-1335/? I/SapService: Avoid unregister when receiver it is not registered\
...
09-26 22:02:00.334 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@44c59d4\
09-26 22:02:00.335 1335-1335/? D/HidDevService: Received stop request...Stopping profile...\
09-26 22:02:00.335 1335-1335/? D/HidDevService: stop()\
09-26 22:02:00.335 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@44c59d4\
09-26 22:02:00.335 1335-1335/? E/BluetoothAdapterService: onProfileServiceStateChanged() serviceName=com.android.bluetooth.hid.HidDevService, state=10, Message sending\
09-26 22:02:00.335 1335-1335/? D/HidDevService: notifyProfileServiceStateChanged\
09-26 22:02:00.336 1348-1348/? D/BluetoothSap: Proxy object disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.336 1348-1348/? D/SapProfile: Bluetooth service disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.339 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothSap: Proxy object disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.339 10977-10977/? D/SapProfile: Bluetooth service disconnected\
09-26 22:02:00.340 677-1701/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10016 networkInfo: [type: WIFI[] - WIFI, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "SiuFuiHse - Downstair", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]\
09-26 22:02:00.341 1335-1335/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@44c59d4\
09-26 22:02:00.342 1335-11452/? W/bt_osi_thread: run_thread: thread id 11452, thread name media_worker exited\
09-26 22:02:00.343 1335-1335/? E/BluetoothAdapterService: handleMessage() - Message: 1\
09-26 22:02:00.343 1335-1335/? E/BluetoothAdapterService: processProfileServiceStateChanged() serviceName=com.android.bluetooth.hid.HidService, state=10, Before synchronized\
...
09-26 22:02:00.391 4751-4751/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON\
09-26 22:02:00.391 4751-4751/? D/BluetoothAdapter: enableRadio(): BT is already enabled..!\
09-26 22:02:00.392 677-833/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.392 677-833/? D/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth is turned off, stop adv\
09-26 22:02:00.395 1348-1706/? D/BluetoothMap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.395 1348-1706/? E/BluetoothMap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$2@7fbf034\
                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1352)\
                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1553)\
                                                   at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:723)\
                                                   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$1.onBluetoothStateChange(BluetoothMap.java:64)\
                                                   at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothStateChangeCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothStateChangeCallback.java:55)\
                                                   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)\
09-26 22:02:00.396 10977-11493/? D/BluetoothInputDevice: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.401 4751-4777/? D/BeaconManager[7.1.17.0]: BleScanHelper.MSG_CALL_START_LESCAN - isFilterScanFailed/discovering:false/true\
09-26 22:02:00.404 10977-10989/? D/BluetoothPbap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.404 4751-4777/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON\
09-26 22:02:00.405 4751-4777/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON\
09-26 22:02:00.406 10977-10989/? E/BluetoothPbap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothPbap$2@6fce766\
                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1352)\
                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1553)\
                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:723)\
                                                      at android.bluetooth.BluetoothPbap$1.onBluetoothStateChange(BluetoothPbap.java:121)\
                                                      at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothStateChangeCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothStateChangeCallback.java:55)\
                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)\
09-26 22:02:00.406 10977-10988/? D/BluetoothPan: onBluetoothStateChange on: false\
09-26 22:02:00.407 4751-4777/? D/BluetoothAdapter: appoCount is = 1\
09-26 22:02:00.407 4751-4777/? I/BeaconManager[7.1.17.0]: BleScanHelper.directStopLeScan - call BleScanner.stopScan()\
09-26 22:02:00.407 11594-11605/? D/BluetoothInputDevice: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.408 4751-4777/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON\
09-26 22:02:00.409 4751-4777/? D/BluetoothAdapter: appoCount is = 1\
09-26 22:02:00.411 4751-4777/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON\
09-26 22:02:00.411 4751-4777/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan\
09-26 22:02:00.412 1348-1365/? D/BluetoothPbap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.413 1348-1365/? E/BluetoothPbap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothPbap$2@198e3d2\
                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1352)\
                                                    at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1553)\
                                                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:723)\
                                                    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothPbap$1.onBluetoothStateChange(BluetoothPbap.java:121)\
                                                    at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothStateChangeCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothStateChangeCallback.java:55)\
                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)\
09-26 22:02:00.413 10977-10989/? D/BluetoothMap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.414 1335-1720/? E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler: android.uid.bcmgr, msg: MESSAGE_STOP_SCAN\
09-26 22:02:00.415 10977-10989/? E/BluetoothMap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$2@f565b54\
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1352)\
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1553)\
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:723)\
                                                     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$1.onBluetoothStateChange(BluetoothMap.java:64)\
                                                     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothStateChangeCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothStateChangeCallback.java:55)\
                                                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)\
09-26 22:02:00.415 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: stop scan\
09-26 22:02:00.415 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: delete FilterIndex - 9\
09-26 22:02:00.416 1335-9889/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=4\
09-26 22:02:00.417 1348-1369/? D/BluetoothPan: onBluetoothStateChange on: false\
09-26 22:02:00.418 1348-1705/? D/BluetoothSap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.418 8265-8351/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.418 8265-8351/? D/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth is turned off, stop adv\
09-26 22:02:00.420 10977-10988/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
09-26 22:02:00.420 10977-10988/? D/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth is turned off, stop adv\
09-26 22:02:00.421 1348-1706/? D/BluetoothInputDevice: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false\
...
09-26 22:02:07.623 677-4055/? D/SecContentProvider: called from android.uid.bluetooth:1002\
09-26 22:02:07.625 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothExpListController: onScanningStateChanged :: started = true\
09-26 22:02:07.625 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothSettings: onScanningStateChanged :: is start scanning true\
09-26 22:02:07.625 10977-10977/? V/BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver: Received: android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED\
09-26 22:02:07.626 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothSettings: onReceive :: getAction = android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED\
09-26 22:02:07.627 1335-9889/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=2c6064dd-0da9-4025-a15b-f4e8898076fc\
09-26 22:02:07.628 10977-10977/? D/ViewRootImpl@be04623[BluetoothScanDialog]: dispatchAttachedToWindow\
09-26 22:02:07.633 677-1967/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setInexact Intent (T:2/F:0/AC:false) 20180926T221529 - CU:10016/CP:2010\
09-26 22:02:07.633 677-1985/? V/WindowManager: Relayout Window\{9839124d0 u0 com.android.settings/com.samsung.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothScanDialog\}: viewVisibility=0 req=512x665 WM.LayoutParams\{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) sim=#120 ty=1 fl=#1820002 fmt=-3 wanim=0x1030392 surfaceInsets=Rect(2, 2 - 2, 2) needsMenuKey=2 naviIconColor=0\}\
09-26 22:02:07.634 271-271/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=876 createSurf (5x5),1 flag=4, com.android.settings/com.samsung.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothScanDialog\
09-26 22:02:07.636 677-731/? D/WindowManager: set systemUiVisibility of statusbar : systemUiFlags= 0x8 fullscreenStackSysUiFlag= 0x0\
09-26 22:02:07.662 677-1985/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus entered window: 10977\
09-26 22:02:07.664 2010-11693/? I/NearbyMessages: NetworkPollManager:  RPC was requested, but deemed unnecessary. -- metadata\{ service_id: 0 \}\
09-26 22:02:07.668 10977-10977/? D/ViewRootImpl@be04623[BluetoothScanDialog]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[128,191][640,856] result=0x27 surface=\{isValid=true -2081433600\} surfaceGenerationChanged=true\
09-26 22:02:07.668 10977-10977/? D/ViewRootImpl@be04623[BluetoothScanDialog]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface=\{isValid=true -2081433600\} hwInitialized=true\
09-26 22:02:07.671 677-1986/? D/WindowManager: adjustSystemUiVisibilityLw : vis= 0x8\
09-26 22:02:07.675 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothExpListAdapter: getGroupView :: groupPosition = 0,  getPreferenceCount = 0 , isExpanded = true\
09-26 22:02:07.681 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothExpListAdapter: getGroupView :: groupPosition = 1,  getPreferenceCount = 0 , isExpanded = true\
09-26 22:02:07.684 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothExpListAdapter: getGroupView :: groupPosition = 2,  getPreferenceCount = 0 , isExpanded = true\
09-26 22:02:07.687 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothExpListAdapter: getGroupView :: groupPosition = 3,  getPreferenceCount = 0 , isExpanded = true\
09-26 22:02:07.690 10977-10977/? D/AbsListView:  in onLayout changed \
09-26 22:02:07.690 10977-10977/? D/BluetoothSettings: onReceive :: getAction = android.bluetooth.adapter.action.SCAN_MODE_CHANGED\
09-26 22:02:07.706 677-1970/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window\{9839124d0 u0 com.android.settings/com.samsung.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothScanDialog\} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING\
09-26 22:02:07.707 10977-10977/? D/ViewRootImpl@be04623[BluetoothScanDialog]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(128, 191 - 640, 856) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1\
09-26 22:02:07.707 10977-10977/? D/ViewRootImpl@be04623[BluetoothScanDialog]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1\
09-26 22:02:07.707 10977-10977/? D/ViewRootImpl@be04623[BluetoothScanDialog]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface=\{isValid=true -2081433600\}\
09-26 22:02:07.707 10977-10977/? V/InputMethodManager: Not IME target window, ignoring\
09-26 22:02:07.721 677-32478/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window\{9839124d0 u0 com.android.settings/com.samsung.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothScanDialog\} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN\
09-26 22:02:07.726 677-842/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.settings/com.samsung.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothScanDialog: +523ms\
09-26 22:02:07.729 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=2c6064dd-0da9-4025-a15b-f4e8898076fc, clientIf=6, status=0\
09-26 22:02:07.730 2010-15582/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6 mClientIf=0\
09-26 22:02:07.734 1335-18789/? D/BtGatt.GattService: getScanSettings() Packgage: com.google.android.gms, isForeground: false, scanMode: 0\
09-26 22:02:07.738 1335-1720/? E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler: com.google.uid.shared, msg: MESSAGE_START_SCAN\
09-26 22:02:07.740 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: handling starting scan\
09-26 22:02:07.740 1335-1719/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON\
...
09-26 22:02:07.746 1335-1719/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON\
09-26 22:02:07.746 2010-11694/? I/BeaconBle: Client requested scan, settings=BleSettings [scanMode=LOW_LATENCY, callbackType=ALL_MATCHES, reportDelayMillis=0, 6 filters, 1 clients, callingClientName=Nearby]\
09-26 22:02:07.747 271-271/? D/SurfaceFlinger:   Display[0] configurations (* current):\
                                                   * 0: 768x1024, xdpi=159.895004, ydpi=159.567993, refresh=16666667\
                                                 numHwLayers=4, flags=00000000\
                                                   type   |  handle  | hint | flag | tr | blnd |   format    |     source crop (l,t,r,b)      |          frame         | name \
                                               -----------+----------+------+------+----+------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+------\
                                                      HWC | b16ca420 | 0002 | 0000 | 00 | 0100 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  768.0, 1024.0 |    0,    0,  768, 1024 | com.firstproj.funapp/com.firstproj.funapp.MainActivity\
                                                      HWC | b16ca720 | 0002 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  516.0,  669.0 |  146,  215,  621,  831 | com.android.settings/com.samsung.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothScanDialog\
                                                      HWC | b16ca000 | 0002 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  768.0,   24.0 |    0,    0,  768,   24 | StatusBar\
                                                FB TARGET | b52226e0 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  768.0, 1024.0 |    0, \
09-26 22:02:07.747 271-271/? D/SurfaceFlinger:    0,  768, 1024 | HWC_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET\
09-26 22:02:07.752 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=1\
09-26 22:02:07.752 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0\
09-26 22:02:07.753 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: set filter index= 8 for clientIf= 6\
09-26 22:02:07.753 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: addFilterToController: 6\
09-26 22:02:07.754 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=6, availableSpace=31\
09-26 22:02:07.754 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0\
09-26 22:02:07.754 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter() : onFoundTimeout | onLostTimeout | onFoundCount | numOfTrackingEntries | scanFilterRssiThreshold | trackableScanFilterRssiThreshold | matchMode\
09-26 22:02:07.754 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter() : __________500__|________10000__|___________1__|___________________0__|___________________-128__|____________________________-128__|________1_\
09-26 22:02:07.756 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=12\
09-26 22:02:07.756 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0\
09-26 22:02:07.756 1335-1719/? E/BtGatt.ScanManager: default value of curScanSetting 0 is choosen\
09-26 22:02:07.756 1335-1719/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON\
09-26 22:02:07.757 1335-1719/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON\
09-26 22:02:07.758 1335-1719/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON\
09-26 22:02:07.758 1335-1719/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON\
09-26 22:02:07.762 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() [LCD ON] scan param set to 800 / 8000 (units)\
09-26 22:02:07.763 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanParamSetupCompleted() status=0, clientIf=6\
09-26 22:02:07.763 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0\
09-26 22:02:07.767 271-271/? D/SurfaceFlinger:   Display[0] configurations (* current):\
                                                   * 0: 768x1024, xdpi=159.895004, ydpi=159.567993, refresh=16666667\
                                                 numHwLayers=5, flags=00000000\
                                                   type   |  handle  | hint | flag | tr | blnd |   format    |     source crop (l,t,r,b)      |          frame         | name \
                                               -----------+----------+------+------+----+------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+------\
                                                      HWC | b16ca420 | 0002 | 0000 | 00 | 0100 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  768.0, 1024.0 |    0,    0,  768, 1024 | com.firstproj.funapp/com.firstproj.funapp.MainActivity\
                                                     GLES | 00000000 | 0000 | 0001 | 00 | 0105 | ? ffffffff  |    0.0,    0.0,   -1.0,   -1.0 |    0,    0,  768, 1024 | DimLayerController/Stack=0\
                                                     GLES | b16caa80 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  516.0,  668.0 |  141,  208,  627,  837 | com.android.settings/com.samsung.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothScanDialog\
                                                     GLES | b16caba0 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  768.0\
09-26 22:02:07.767 271-271/? D/SurfaceFlinger: ,   24.0 |    0,    0,  768,   24 | StatusBar\
                                                FB TARGET | b5222620 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  768.0, 1024.0 |    0,    0,  768, 1024 | HWC_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET\
09-26 22:02:07.771 2010-11694/? I/BeaconBle: 'L' hardware scan: 6 filters, scanMode=2, reportdelay=0, callback type=1, #clients=2, workSource=WorkSource\{10016 com.google.android.gms\}\
09-26 22:02:07.775 2010-11694/? I/BeaconBle: Starting scan on OS scanner. BT state: 12\
09-26 22:02:07.775 2010-11694/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan\
...
...
09-26 22:02:07.901 1335-1719/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON\
09-26 22:02:07.904 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=8, status=0, action=1\
09-26 22:02:07.904 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 8 status - 0\
09-26 22:02:07.904 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: set filter index= 12 for clientIf= 8\
09-26 22:02:07.904 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: addFilterToController: 5\
09-26 22:02:07.905 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=8, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=5, availableSpace=29\
09-26 22:02:07.905 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 8 status - 0\
09-26 22:02:07.905 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter() : onFoundTimeout | onLostTimeout | onFoundCount | numOfTrackingEntries | scanFilterRssiThreshold | trackableScanFilterRssiThreshold | matchMode\
09-26 22:02:07.905 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter() : __________500__|________10000__|___________1__|___________________0__|___________________-128__|____________________________-128__|________1_\
09-26 22:02:07.906 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=8, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=11\
09-26 22:02:07.906 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 8 status - 0\
09-26 22:02:07.906 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: set filter index= 3 for clientIf= 8\
09-26 22:02:07.906 1335-1719/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: addFilterToController: 2\
09-26 22:02:07.909 1335-1432/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=8, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=2, availableSpace=31\
```

Comment: Understand that the BluetoothMedic cannot solve all Bluetooth problems.  It only solves problems that can be fixed by turning Bluetooth off then back on.  It appears your device may have experienced an issue it cannot solve.

Comment: Understand and thanks, it would be nice if the Medic has an option send an notification when it detects the problem and cannot be fixed.